# Less CSS border radius mixin not 0

Tags: less

I want to add a Guard on my border-radius mixin, which dosn't give any output if the border-radius is 0. My LESS Code works great, until I use more than one argument.

```
.border-radius (@radius) when (@radius > 0) {
  border-radius: @radius;
}

.dosnt-work {
  .border-radius (5px 10px 5px 10px);
}

.works-correctly {
  .border-radius (5px);
}

.works-correctly-too {
  .border-radius (0px);
}
```

Is this possible without creating 4 different mixins?

Comment: why would you want to do that? What happens when you want to override an existing border radius and set it to `0`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're only accepting one parameter, when you use something like "5px 10px 5px 10px" it's comparing that entire string to 0 and a string can't be reasonably considered to be greater than zero. The only way around this would be to have another mixin for multiple parameters. You can use the same name, `.border-radius`: just define it again with multiple parameters. LESS will workout which to call based on the number of parameters.

However, I think this is a bit misguided in general. Why do you want to ignore border-radius values of zero? How else can you override a previous rule to turn off border-radius?

Answer (score 0):

```
.border-radius(@radius) when not(@radius = 0) {
   border-radius: @radius;
}
```

Note however this won't work for arguments like (0 0), (0 0 0 0) etc...